# Determining if TimeoutHandler has timed out

Tags: go

I'm using `http.TimeoutHandler` to return a timeout to the client. This works fine, the problem is that I'm trying to call some code if the timeout has been triggered. I've looked through the docs and the source code, and I can't find a good way of doing this. The response just goes back to the client and I can't find a way to do any introspection on the context or the ResponseWriter etc.

The calling code doesn't have access to the context, so I can't inspect it. The actual struct that the `http.ResponseWriter` is writing to within `http.TimeoutHandler` *does* put the information in that I need (it's the `http.timeoutWriter`), but I can't access it because the `http.ResponseWriter` interface doesn't support accessing those variables.

I'm not overly experience in Go, but I can't help but think that I'm just going to have to re-implement my own `http.TimeoutHandler` because I can't see a way to do what I need to.

Have I missed something?

Comment: to add on Burak Serdar answer, https://play.golang.org/p/up3qBHbADYv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the source for `TimeoutHandler`, it sets the context in the request to a context with timeout. That means, in your handler you can use the context to see if timeout happened:

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request) {
  ...
  if r.Context().Err()==context.DeadlineExceeded {
     // Timeout happened
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah. I knew I must've been missing something obvious.